# ZF2: How to render view from other module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view

I have a problem with rendering view from other module.

For example: I'm on page news.phtml  and I need to add  'Add comment' page. The view of adding comments is in other module 'Comments' in file add.phtml.

I have no idea how to include this file on news page.
I've tried something like this:

```
echo $this->render('module/Comments/view/comments/index/add.phtml'); 
echo $this->render('../../Comments/view/comments/index/add.phtml');
```

but nothing works.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `partial` view helper

```
echo $this->partial('comments/index/add');
```

Comment: I've tried that too, I had problem with something different (second parameter was required) and now It's ok, anyway thanks