# How to render a view from another module outsidethe view folder in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, partial-views, partials, zend-view

I want to bundle the whole error handling in one module. It's working so far, but the error template is still the default `[project root]/module/Application/view/error/index.phtml`. I want to use it, but wrapped by my additional code. For this I need to add the default exception template as a partial. It's not possible (anymore) to pass the module name to the Partial view helper. So I tried this (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24733099/2019043)):

**`[project root]/module/ErrorHandling/view/exception.phtml`**

```
echo $this->partial('Application/error/index');
```

But it didn't work:

> Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException: Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "Application/error/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file in /var/www/.../my-project/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:494

It works only for views from the `/module/{AnotherModule}/view/{another-module}` subfolders.

**How to get a view from another module (but outside the `/module/{AnotherModule}/view/{another-module}` subfolder) rendered as a partial?**

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to add the desired view to the template map of the View Manager, e.g.:

**`config/autoload/global.php`**

```
return [
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_map' => [
            'default_zf_error_view' => __DIR__ . '/../../module/Application/view/error/index.phtml'
        ]
    ]
];
```

It works, but it still would be interesting to know, how to solve this issue a bit cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add it in `global.php`

It will be enough to add it to the `module.config.php` of the module. Those views will be also accessible inside the other modules because ZF2 merges all config files of your different modules. Read more on this here [in the documentation in the chapter **Advanced Configuration Tricks**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html).

So in `module.config.php`:

```
return [

    //...

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_map' => [
            'default_zf_error_view' => __DIR__ . '/../../module/Application/view/error/index.phtml'
        ]
    ]

    //...

];
```

In the controller of any other module you can now do:

```
$viewModel->setTemplate('default_zf_error_view');
```